# MVC parent and child nested views returning models

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Suppose I have a parent.cshtml view with a parentModel, and a child.cshtml view with a childModel.
This child action is `[ChildActionOnly]` and is rendered in parent.cshtml: `@Html.Action("ChildAction")`.

Now, in controller/ParentAction

```
public ActionResult ParentAction() {return View();}
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult ParentAction(ParentModel parentmodel) { 
    if(!ModelState.IsValid) {
      ...
      ModelState.AddModelError("", "parent view has an error");
    }
    return View(parentmodel); // pass the ball back to user
}
```

in controller/ChildAction

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult ChildAction() {return View();}
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult ChildAction(ChildModel childmodel) { 
     if(!ModelState.IsValid) {
       ...
       ModelState.AddModelError("", "child view has an error");
    }
    //??? return ParentView(parentmodel, childmodel) ??? how do i do this??? 
}
```

In the child action, how do I return to the ParentView (that also renders the ChildView), and preserve the data in their models?

EDIT:-----

My point is how not to do that. `return View(childmodel);` from child action will not get us what we want to see, because it will only give us a 'partial' page with child view only, the parent part is missing. `RedirectToAction("ParentAction");` will give us full view again, but it will lose the models. Not sure how to handle returning models in nested views. That's where I am stuck.

Comment: Try putting your childModel as a child of your parentModel. Pass childModel to a child controller and subsequently ignore it inside your parent controller.

Comment: @Aleksey: child.cshtml has a Form and a Submit Button in it to post information about the childModel. [HttpPost] public ActionResult ChildAction(ChildModel childmodel) { ...  So, I don't see your point how ParentModel wraps around ChildModel? Could you show the code sample please? Also probably as themarcuz said, everyone handles its own model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to create a common model that wraps the `ParentModel` and `ChildModel` else put the `ChildModel` as a property of the `ParentModel`. Instead of calling a child action and render the child view I would suggest you use `Html.RenderPartial` in this case.

Let say the `ParentModel` wraps the `ChildModel` then from the `ParentView.cshtml` you could render `the ChildView.cshtml` by,

```
@Html.Partial("ChildView", Model.ChildModel);
```

Now from the child post action you have to build the `ParentModel` and return the `ParentView`.

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult ChildAction(ChildModel childmodel) { 
    if(!ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
       ...
       ModelState.AddModelError("", "child view has an error");
    } 

    ParentModel model = .. build the model from querying database.

    return View("ParentView", model);
}
```

Comment: Looks like having a 'customControl' in mvc is not as straight forward as asp.net web form. This return view/partialview structure is rather flat and works better with ajax updating the dom object.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you don't. Why should you return the parent model in the child action? Every action will handle its own model

Comment: I know we don't do that. But I can't take it as an answer. My point is how not to do that. return View(childmodel); from child action will not get us what we want to see, because it will only give us a 'partial' page with child view only, the parent part is missing. RedirectToAction("ParentAction"); will give us full view again, but it will lose the models. Not sure how to handle returning models in nested views. That's where I am stuck.